# What is this property called for a function? $f(f(x))=f(x)$

Tags: functions, terminology, function-and-relation-composition

I am looking for a name for the following types of functions. Suppose that for function *f*, we have:
$$f(x)=y_x$$ and $$f(f(x))=y_x$$
Is there any name for this property?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Such a function is called [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Some examples:

- The absolute value: $\operatorname{abs}: \mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$.
- Any [lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) operation like $\max$, $\min$, $\cap$, $\cup$, $\gcd$, etc., can be transformed into an idempotent function. For example $f_1(x)=\max(0,x)$, $f_2(n) = \gcd(n, 60)$ and so on.
- Projections, e.g. $\pi_1\big((x,y,z)\big) = (0,y,z)$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I would add that this particular case is in fact a projection!

Comment: @GPerez Which case?

Comment: OP. He has $f^2 = f$.

Comment: The identity function is idempotent too :D

Comment: @GPerez Why it is a projection?

Comment: The statement in the question (and the notion of idempotence) clearly only makes sense for unary functions. So the phrase "If you want an unary function" is misplaced, and you should instead rephrase that bullet point to only apply to those operators transformed (by supplying a fixed argument) into unary functions.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I don't mind calling $\vee$ or $\max$ idempotent (I disagree that it doesn't make sense), but you are right, in the context of the question the second bullet was formulated silly, fixed now. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: @dtldarek I thought projections were defined as a map onto a subset where the composition with itself is again the same map. Wikipedia says so too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28mathematics%29

Comment: @GPerez In the terminology I'm used to _projection_ implies some additional structure, as there is already term _idempotence_ which takes care of the general case.

Answer (score 5):

Idempotent functions

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence

It is common in computer science, in which you may want the result of an operation to be the same no matter how many times someone performs it. This is especially important in web-apps.

In maths an example would be a projection of a vector into a lower dimensional space.

Comment: It is worth noting that the "computer science version" is just the ordinary idempotence, only applied to _states_ (e.g. world state, or program state, server state, object state, whatever the context is).

Answer (score 1):

A function that has the same result when applied once as it does when applied more than once is known as an [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) function.