# Composition of a function equals the function

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

So, I've been wondering about composing functions, and came up with the idea of finding $f(x)$ where $f(f(x))=f(x)$

I've found some trivial solutions, like $f(x)$ being a constant, and $f(x)=x$, but I'm also wondering if there are any other solutions, and if there are, what the properties all of these share are.

I've got an intuition this has probably got something to do with fixed points, but from there I'm lost.

Nice opportunity to learn some new math, I guess.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153717/what-is-this-property-called-for-a-function-ffx-fx)